# Camel Routing using Headers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel

I have a spring boot camel app.
I am reading from an incoming Kafka topic queue and running a processor that lookup a new destination topic from the Redis cache. In the processor, I add this as a new camel header.

```
exchange.getIn().setHeader("destTopic", cachelookupvalue);
 LOG.info ("RouterProcessor Dest Topic set to:= {}", exchange.getIn().getHeader("destTopic"));
```

This seems to work, and the log shows it set.

On returning to the route builder class

```
public class RouterBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
...
//setup env properties etc 
 @Override
    public void configure() {

from("kafka:" + SRC_TOPIC + "?brokers=" + SRC_BROKER).routeId("myRoute")  
 .log("Sending message to kafka: ${header.destTopic}" )            
 .process(processor)
 .to("kafka:${header.destTopic}?brokers="+DEST_BROKER) //not working

but 
  //.to("kafka:webhook-channel_1-P101?brokers="+DEST_BROKER) //this works syntax
```

If i hardcode the the ${header.destTopic} expression it work but not if i try to use the header in the .to dsl it does not.

The Log .log("Sending message to kafka: ${header.destTopic}" seems to be right topic.

I am not sure if it's a syntax problem or if I'm missing a step.

The error output is

> Failed delivery for (MessageId: 972B795CF230E52-0000000000000001 on
> ExchangeId: 972B795CF230E52-0000000000000001). Exhausted after
> delivery attempt: 1 caught:
> org.apache.kafka.common.errors.InvalidTopicException:
> ${header.destTopic}

Answer (score 0):

Headers , properties and body ..etc  are dynamic values in camel so you must use toD(to Dynamic)

```
.toD("kafka:${headers.destTopic}?brokers="+DEST_BROKER) //not working
```